# MySQL: Delete rows that have a value in another select

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to delete rows from a table based on what's not in one of the keys (previous programmer didn't make sure that values aren't removed if a key is missing, yada yada) and this is the statment I tried:

```
DELETE FROM studentinstruments 
WHERE studentID IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT studentID 
FROM studentinstruments 
WHERE studentID NOT IN 
(SELECT ID FROM students));
```

And I get an error of "ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'studentinstruments' for update in FROM clause" and I have no idea what's wrong with it. What would the corrections be to make this statement work?

Comment: I think that the problem is that you cant UPDATE/DELETE from the same table you are selecting from. Try creating a temporary table and select data from 'SELECT DISTINCT studentID 
FROM studentinstruments 
WHERE studentID NOT IN 
(SELECT ID FROM students)' statement. Then use that table to delete from `studentinstruments `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use it directly instead of using multiple subquery, it would do the same thing.

```
DELETE FROM studentinstruments 
WHERE studentID NOT IN 
(SELECT ID FROM students);
```

Comment: Well crap, I was making it too complicated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Mysql, you can't make modification in the same table, which you have used in the select part.

Instead try using the instance.

```
DELETE FROM studentinstruments
WHERE studentID IN
(
    SELECT studentId
    FROM (SELECT * FROM studentinstruments) AS something
    WHERE something.studentID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM studentinstruments)
)
```